# Installing terminator on cygwin

Tags: unix, terminal, cygwin, terminator

After going through a lot of sites about best terminal for system admins I was trying to install on Cygwin. Unfortunately, I did not find any good site with instruction about how to do it.

Is anyone done this before? Please help me with steps and packages that I need to install.

Also is there any terminals I can try (like Cygwin)?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know since what version, but now you can install terminator just from the Cygwin installer. And runs great

Regards

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use cygwinports, you can actually install all of terminator's dependencies from the cygwin installer, except for terminator itself.

In the cygwin installer select and install:
`python-dbus
python-gobject
python-gtk2.0
python-vte (under GNOME tab for some reason)
GConf2`

Then, pull down the latest terminator tarball from https://launchpad.net/terminator/+download and extract it somewhere. In a administrator terminal just run `python setup.py install` and as long as you have a running X server just running `terminator` will work perfectly.

Comment: I tried your method with terminator-0.97 to 1.90 and after install a bunch of packages it didn't work. It complains about psutil and after commenting this it complains about some static imports. The good news? Now cygwin includes terminator

Answer (score 1):

The sources about how to install **terminator** are a bit obscures. What I did, and may help you, was this: (although I'm still having segmentation faults errors)

1. Update your Cygwin to the latest
2. Open a Cygwin terminal and run: (if you have the x86 version use that. The idea of this step is to use Cygwin Ports)

   cygstart -- /your/cygwin/path/setup-x86_64.exe -K http://cygwinports.org/ports.gpg
3. In the section **Choose A Download Site:**

   - Add "http://downloads.sourceforge.net/cygwin-ports"
   - Add " ftp://ftp.cygwinports.org/pub/cygwinports"
   - Select another mirror close to you

   Check that you have a total of three URLs selected
4. It may show you warning about not loading the .ini configuration but ignore them (Note: I looked for different port URLs but the official ones threw me errors and I could not pass this step, that's why I used alternatives URLs)
5. First, you need to install the packages for the X Window:

http://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/setup.html

Basically they are:

- xorg-server (required, the Cygwin/X X Server)
- xinit (required, scripts for starting the X server: xinit, startx, startwin (and a shortcut on the Start Menu to run it), startxdmcp.bat )
- xorg-docs (optional, man pages)

Also search and select the **terminator** package

It takes quite a while before it finishes.

1. Go to Start->All Programs->Cygwin-X->X Win Server (windows tool bar)
2. A xterm window should open. Type:

   terminator

You should know have terminator with Cygwin.

Note: After I run terminator I get this error:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/terminatorlib/terminator.py:87: Warning: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::sm-connect after class was initialised
  self.gnome_program = gnome.init(APP_NAME, APP_VERSION)
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/terminatorlib/terminator.py:87: Warning: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::show-crash-dialog after class was initialised
  self.gnome_program = gnome.init(APP_NAME, APP_VERSION)
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/terminatorlib/terminator.py:87: Warning: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::display after class was initialised
  self.gnome_program = gnome.init(APP_NAME, APP_VERSION)
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/terminatorlib/terminator.py:87: Warning: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::default-icon after class was initialised
  self.gnome_program = gnome.init(APP_NAME, APP_VERSION)
Warning: python-keybinder is not installed. This means the hide_window shortcut will be unavailable
Unable to bind hide_window key, another instance/window has it.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I've looking to fix this issue but sadly I couldn't find anything. If you use Cygwin x86 your outcome can be different.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: The question about how to install terminator *on* Cygwin, not how to install Cygwin.

Comment: Very sorry, lack of sleep. Edited.